# Cannot Close Menu on clicking a link MenuItem

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have `AppBar` component with a menu. Every time I click on any of the links, navigation happens, but the menu doesn't close.

```
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes';

class AppBar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    anchorEl: null
  };

   handleCommonMenuOpen = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  }

  handleCommonMenuClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  };

  render() {
    const { anchorEl } = this.state;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const renderCommonMenu = (<Menu
                            anchorEl={anchorEl}
                            id="tutorials-menu"
                            anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
                            transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
                            open={isMenuOpen}
                            onClose={this.handleCommonMenuClose}
>
  <MenuItem  onClick={this.handleCommonMenuClose} component={Link} to={ROUTES.AUTHENTICATION_DOC}>Authentication</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleCommonMenuClose} component={Link} to={ROUTES.REALTIMEDB_DOC}>Realtime DB</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleCommonMenuClose} component={Link} to={ROUTES.HOSTING_DOC}>Hosting</MenuItem>
</Menu>)
    return(
     <div>
        <Button aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="tutorials-menu" onClick={this.handleCommonMenuOpen} color="inherit">Tutorials</Button>
        {renderCommonMenu}
       <Route path={ROUTES.AUTHENTICATION_DOC} component={AuthenticationDoc} />
       <Route path={ROUTES.REALTIMEDB_DOC} component={ReattimeDBDoc} /> 
     </div>)
  }
}
export default AppBar;
```

If I click the `handleCommonMenuClose`, it will result in an error.

> "cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Could anybody help me out to resolve this issue, please?

Comment: Can you try passing your ```handleCommonMenuClose``` method to each of your MenuItem as ```onClick``` prop. I think on click you will be routed and then the method call will close the menu.

Comment: When I call the handleCommonMenuClose on click, I will get below error.

"cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: Where did you put the ```onClick``` method? on ```Menu``` or on each ```MenuItem```

Comment: On each MenuItem as <MenuItem onClick={this.handleCommonMenuClose} component={Link} to={ROUTES.AUTHENTICATION_DOC}>Authentication</MenuItem>
I can't actually change the state.

Comment: Why not render the ```Menu``` directly in the ```render``` method? For example [here](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#SimpleMenu.js)

Comment: Can you share a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) or a stack snippet where the problem can be reproduced?